# Dart: how to bind generic methods to nested generic parameters?

Tags: generics, dart

Is there a way to create a generic method that is bound to a generic parameter? Here below my example:

```
class Taste {}

class Vanilla extends Taste {}

class Chocolate extends Taste {}
```

```
class IceCream<T extends Taste> {
  int tasteLevel = 0;

  //only this taste can be used
  void enhanceTaste(T taste) {
    tasteLevel++;
  }
}

class ChocolateIceCream extends IceCream<Chocolate> {}

class VanillaIceCream extends IceCream<Vanilla> {}
```

Here is the class implementing the generic method **enhanceTastes()**.
Is it possible to bound the method parameter *taste* to the *_iceCreamList* taste?
Perhaps a way to define that "T=I< E>" so the type of "E" is in some way derived by "T".

```
class IceCreamBox<T extends IceCream> {
  List<T> _iceCreamList = List<T>();

  //GENERIC METHOD
  void enhanceTastes<E extends Taste /*of _iceCreamList*/>(E taste) {
    for (T iceCream in _iceCreamList) {
      iceCream.enhanceTaste(taste);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the test. **box.enhanceTastes(Vanilla()) shouldn't be allowed**.

```
class TestBox {
  void test() {
    IceCreamBox<ChocolateIceCream> box = IceCreamBox<ChocolateIceCream>();
    box.enhanceTastes(Chocolate()); //OK
    box.enhanceTastes(Vanilla()); //I WANT THE COMPILER TO COMPLAIN! BECAUSE THIS IS A CHOCOLATE ICE CREAM BOX!
  }
}
```